# Booking reservation room with Google Calendar API and CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, calendar, google-calendar-api

My company have only 2 meeting rooms while having many staff want to use this. The leader required me to make an web app for staff that used to booking room through an calendar. One of requirements is using Google Calendar API for calendar and CakePHP for code. In summary, this spec is :

- User function : Create, view meeting scheduled of them (using Google Calendar).
- Admin function : Create, read, edit, delete users and also their meeting scheduled (also using Google Calendar api).

I don't have any idea also knowlegde about using Google Calendar API for this project. Anyone can give me an example, solution or link about this ? Thanks so much and sorry for my bad English :(

Sorry, this is the sample web that I want to make like : http://www.vanderbilt.edu/psychological_sciences/reservation-calendar.php

Comment: You need to share of your code first?

Comment: Here you can write only English,

Answer (score 1):

After sometimes googling, I found a Calendar Plugin for CakePHP 2.x.

The CakePHP Full Calendar Plugin allows you to easily integrate the jQuery based Full Calendar application with your CakePHP application for a slick ajax event calendar.

Just see [CakePHP-Full-Calendar-Plugin](https://github.com/silasmontgomery/CakePHP-Full-Calendar-Plugin)